# What calls the greet() method in HelloWorldAnonymousClasses?

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class, local-class

In the HelloWorldAnonymousClasses example program ([from here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/HelloWorldAnonymousClasses.java)):

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

public class HelloWorldAnonymousClasses {

    interface HelloWorld {
        public void greet();
        public void greetSomeone(String someone);
    }

    public void sayHello() {

        class EnglishGreeting implements HelloWorld {
            String name = "world";
            public void greet() {
                greetSomeone("world");
            }
            public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
                name = someone;
                System.out.println("Hello " + name);
            }
        }

        HelloWorld englishGreeting = new EnglishGreeting();

        HelloWorld frenchGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
            String name = "tout le monde";
            public void greet() {
                greetSomeone("tout le monde");
            }
            public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
                name = someone;
                System.out.println("Salut " + name);
            }
        };

        HelloWorld spanishGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
            String name = "mundo";
            public void greet() {
                greetSomeone("mundo");
            }
            public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
                name = someone;
                System.out.println("Hola, " + name);
            }
        };
        englishGreeting.greet();
        frenchGreeting.greetSomeone("Fred");
        spanishGreeting.greet();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        HelloWorldAnonymousClasses myApp =
            new HelloWorldAnonymousClasses();
        myApp.sayHello();
    }            
}
```

What calls the `greet()` method of the `englishGreeting` object? I'm confused..

EDIT

Thanks for your replies. I should have spotted that! I was trying to solve another query, which is:

In the example program on
https://gist.github.com/bernii/5697073

In the code

```
this.wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
                System.out.println("Searching ...");
                return webDriver.findElement(By.id("resultStats")) != null;
            }
});
```

what calls the apply() method in the anonymous inner class?

EDIT

I have now asked my second query in a new Question.

Comment: Hint: find `englishGreeting.greet()` on that page.

Comment: it is right there before the main method :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the part of the code shown below three instances of the HelloWorld interface are created:

```
    HelloWorld englishGreeting = new EnglishGreeting();         
    HelloWorld frenchGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
       //...
    };         
    HelloWorld spanishGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
       // ...
    };
```

And here some methods are called on those instances:

```
    englishGreeting.greet();
    frenchGreeting.greetSomeone("Fred");
    spanishGreeting.greet();
```

The french and spanish versions are created using an anonymous inner class. The english version is created from a local class declaration (EnglishGreeting). Note: you don't see local class declarations very often, it's a bit of a construed example.

Answer (score 2):

The greet() method of the englishGreeting object is called after the SpanishGreeting class

```
englishGreeting.greet();
```

Update:
The apply- Method is called from

```
WebDriverWait.until()
```